Flycheck + lsp: How to show errors on a separate buffer?
Flycheck show errors on the side, however, I'd like to see the full error on a separate buffer.
I found this function: https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/blob/master/flycheck.el#L5556-L5559
And I thought using it, however, when I open lsp-mode, it's not defined.
Is there a built-in mechanism to show the full error on a separate buffer?

Simply use the key binding C-c ! l to show Flycheck errors in a separate buffer. No need for a function to show those errors in a separate buffer. Use q to close it.

But I'd like to see only the current error, not the entire list.

Try C-c ! e - which is explain error at point and is displayed in minibufer. Enable the global application menu, or, if you have Emacs version 29 or 30, just click on modeline message FLC[xyz] to see the menu of the flycheck mode.

What do you mean by "not defined" with regards to the function @PeterPetigru, the function you linked is not interactive, so it cannot be called from M-x if that's what you tried.
As far as I can tell there's no built-in mechanism to do exactly what you are describing. flycheck-list-errors (C-c ! l) is the closest you can get. However, that buffer will highlight the current error with flycheck-error-list-highlight face which you coud customize to further differentiate the current error from the others.
